# Why is the value of this spinner not changing?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am writing an app that uses a spinner when creating or editing a course to attach it to a term. The spinner is populated using LiveData from a Room database. I can get the data into the spinner, and I can read the value from the spinner and save it back to the database, but I am at a complete dead end when it comes to setting the value of the spinner back to the value that was chosen when going in to edit the course again.

Here are links to some screenshots of what I mean:

[Course detail activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWwB2.png) In this image, the term ID is shown as 2.

[Edit course activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQzY6.png) This is the same course, but the spinner is showing term ID 1 (the default value).

Everything is getting set up in the onCreate method. I set up the adapter, attach it to the spinner, and observe the IDs to add them to the adapter. Also in onCreate, I call the setSelection method on my spinner to, in an ideal world, set the selection to the value coming in via intent.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



ArrayAdapter<Integer> termArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    termArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    courseTermID.setAdapter(termArrayAdapter);
    TermViewModel termViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TermViewModel.class);
    termViewModel.getAllTermIDs().observe(this, termArrayAdapter::addAll);



courseTermID.setSelection(findValue(courseTermID, getIntent().getStringExtra("termid")));  }
```

The findValue method:

```
private int findValue(Spinner spinner, String value) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim().equals(value.trim())) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

The part that really baffles me is not only is this not working, I can't even hard-code the value of the spinner. If I pass a value in the setSelection method, it just gets ignored.

I've tried being more explicit such as in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350020/populate-spinner-from-livedata-room-database) which is attempting to do the same thing. Either way works to set up the spinner in the first place, but neither way seems to make a difference regarding pulling the value back up later.

I'm really stuck and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Trying moving this line courseTermID.setAdapter(termArrayAdapter)  after courseTermID.setSelection(findValue(courseTermID))

Answer (score 0):

To get the index:

```
private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString) {
        for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(myString)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```